# Perl Out Of Memory when parsing json with regexp inside

Tags: json, perl

I am parsing a very simple json file and perl is running out of memory. I am using the JSON lib from cpan. I am reading the json from a file named "data.json". I am also using the File::Slurper module.

```
use JSON;
use File::Slurper;

my $file = read_text("data.json");
my @data = decode_json($file);
print @data;
```

In my `data.json` file I have an array of objects with regexp inside each obj.

```
[
{
  "val": "test",
  "reg": "m/^(match)/"
}
...3 more entries
]
```

WHen i run this it says

> Out of memory!

how can i bypass this?

Comment: Please provide a demonstration of the problem. It would also be best if you specified which JSON parser you are using as provided by `JSON->backend`.

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as "regexp inside each obj". All you have here is a *string*. And I assure you that code like they code you are using is used to parse JSON like the one you provided every second of every day without running out of memory.

Comment: You should use `read_binary` with `decode_json`, or `read_text` with `from_json`. Otherwise, you are decoding from UTF-8 twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what causes the error in your code. See the following sample code which does same job in a little different way.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my @data = decode_json($file);

say Dumper(\@data);

__DATA__
[
    {
      "val": "test1",
      "reg": "m/^(match)/"
    },
    {
      "val": "test2",
      "reg": "m/^(match)/"
    },
    {
      "val": "test3",
      "reg": "m/^(match)/"
    },
    {
      "val": "test4",
      "reg": "m/^(match)/"
    }
]
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            {
              'val' => 'test1',
              'reg' => 'm/^(match)/'
            },
            {
              'val' => 'test2',
              'reg' => 'm/^(match)/'
            },
            {
              'val' => 'test3',
              'reg' => 'm/^(match)/'
            },
            {
              'reg' => 'm/^(match)/',
              'val' => 'test4'
            }
          ]
        ];
```